# there is a new token in the plist format, can anybody read it in c#?

Tags: c#, ios, plist

So i am dealing with binary plists in c# on pc (not mac). All my search on google on how to read/write binary plists are at least 2 years old. The plist that I am looking at start to appear with iOS 10.

Reading a binary plist is traveling the byte array and processing tokens. The token value gives the data type that comes next. There is a new token value (0x80) and is followed by a single byte. I got the reader working, but the writer is off by 1 on the whole file.

I am going to keep debugging my version, but I wonder if anybody else has hit this problem, and have solved it.

Comment: .plist file isn't a kind of string of XML? Do you have two samples of theses .plist?

Comment: a plist (property list) file can exists in 3 different formats: xml, binary and json. The software that will read the file i produce reads it in binary.